# NSDateFormatter adds excess time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get the current day in *MMMM dd, EEEE* format. And here's what I've done

```
NSDate *utc = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeInterval timeZoneSeconds = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
NSDate *DateInLocalTimezone = [utc dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneSeconds];
fmt.dateFormat = @"MMMM dd, EEEE";
NSString *currentDate = [fmt stringFromDate:DateInLocalTimezone];
```

Given,

- utc = 2016-10-07 08:55:55 +0000
- Timezone = gmt+8
- DateInLocalTimezone = 2016-10-07 16:55:55 +0000
- *currentDate = October 08, Saturday*

currentDate must be October 07, Friday. Why does it add another day when I format my date?

Comment: You added twice +8 hours I think... Remove the stuff with `DateInLocalTimezone`, and just set your current local/time zone to the `NSDateFormatter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDate *now = NSDate.date;
NSDateFormatter *fmt = NSDateFormatter.new;

fmt.dateFormat = @"MMMM dd, EEEE";

NSString *currentDate = [fmt stringFromDate:now];
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSDateFormatter` already deals with time zones. Since you previously added 8 hours to your `NSDate`, you are actually adding 8 hours twice.

Now, a tip:

`NSDate` is a point in time. It counts how many seconds have passed since a reference date (I believe it is Jan 1, 1970 00:00 GMT). Only change `NSDate` if you really want to reference a time before or after that point. Think of `NSDate` as a time machine. If you talk with your friend who lives overseas by phone, you will probably be in different time zones, so the time shown in the clock will be different, but you will both be at the same point in time.

If you want to deal with time zones, use `NSCalendar` or `NSDateFormatter`. They are able to deal not only with time zones but also daylight saving time and some oriental calendars.